# How to match and create a dictionary before and after the match

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

```
import re
s = 'A boy is 31 and girl is 22.'
print(re.findall(r'\S+(?=\s+is\b)', s))
```

out > ['boy', 'girl']

```
print (re.findall(r'\S+(?=\s+)is(?:\s*\S+|$)',s))
```

out > []

if i got out as `['boy',31,'girl',22]` then I can do
`b = dict(zip(list_[::2], list_[1::2]))`

```
Expected Out > {'boy':31, 'girl':22}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = 'A boy is 31 and girl is 22.'
print(dict([(x,int(y)) for x, y in re.findall(r'(\S+)\s+is\s+(\d+)', s)]))
## Or, with dictionary comprehension
print( {x:int(y) for x, y in re.findall(r'(\S+)\s+is\s+(\d+)', s)} )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KkMb8n)

Here, the pattern matches

- `(\S+)` - 1+ non-whitespace chars (Group 1, `x`)
- `\s+is\s+` - `is` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - 1+ digits (Group 2, `y`)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EFWYZY/1).